# The Apple Pay button doe not have the correct design, as “Apple Pay” is added

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, applepay

I am trying to get approval of my app from apple. I am not sure what to do here. Here is the image they gave back indicating the problem

[image]

The problem they mentioned is

Your app uses Apple Pay as a purchasing mechanism but does not use Apple Pay branding and user interface elements appropriately as described in the Apple Pay Human Interface Guidelines. Specifically:

- The Apple Pay button doe not have the correct design, as “Apple Pay” is added.

What to use actually? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to follow Apple's guidelines for "Apple Pay" and that design is not one of those. I'd suggest to follow the official docs:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/buttons-and-marks/

Following your current design, you should be using the "white" variant:

[image: Apple Pay]

and your text can be "Pay with {apple icon}Pay". From size and shapes:

Default cornerRadius is 4 points, 0 points or completely rounded. Minimum height is 30 points, minimum width is 100 points without extra text or 140 points with extra text.

Comment: Recent docs [mention](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/#Offering-Apple-Pay) custom button being allowed, if we show a specific mark beside custom-button.

Comment: What are size limits for said spple-pay-mark (not button)?